# React custom service worker containing require() statement on workbox

Tags: reactjs, workbox

I want to create a custom service worker in react in order to listen to network event (fetch, activate etc).  Some of the events are made by IPFS thus the custom sw.
I want to use workbox as it seems to be the one being maintained now. (sw-precache does not seem to be maintained anymore).
Because the custom sw contains

```js
const IPFS = require('ipfs')
```

I need browserify. I then import that browserified script into the react sw.  My custom sw does not seem to be used in the react sw.

Here is how my package.json file look like

```json
{
  "name": "custom-react-sw",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "@zippie/ipfs-postmsg-proxy": "^3.1.6",
    "ipfs": "^0.50.2",
    "ipfs-postmsg-proxy": "^3.1.1",
    "orbit-db": "^0.26.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.4",
    "workbox": "0.0.0",
    "workbox-cli": "^5.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build && npm run bundle-sw-dependencies && workbox generateSW workbox-config.js",
    "bundle-sw-dependencies": "browserify src/custom-service-worker.js -o build/service-worker-ipfs.js",
    "minify": "terser build/service-worker-ipfs.js --output build/service-worker-ipfs.min.js && npm run cleanup",
    "cleanup": "rm build/service-worker-ipfs.js",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

The custom service worker:

```js
'use strict'
const IPFS = require('ipfs')
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/5.1.2/workbox-sw.js')


if (workbox) {
  console.log(`Yay! Workbox is loaded `);
  self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
    console.log(event)
  })


} else {
  console.log(`Boo! Workbox didn't load `);
}

self.addEventListener('fetch', e => {
  console.log(e)
  console.log(`intercepting ${e.request.method} to ${e.request.url}`)
})
```

Then, the service worker (the one created by react)

```js
// This optional code is used to register a service worker.
// register() is not called by default.

// This lets the app load faster on subsequent visits in production, and gives
// it offline capabilities. However, it also means that developers (and users)
// will only see deployed updates on subsequent visits to a page, after all the
// existing tabs open on the page have been closed, since previously cached
// resources are updated in the background.



const isLocalhost = Boolean(
  window.location.hostname === 'localhost' ||
    // [::1] is the IPv6 localhost address.
    window.location.hostname === '[::1]' ||
    // 127.0.0.0/8 are considered localhost for IPv4.
    window.location.hostname.match(
      /^127(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}$/
    )
);

export function register(config) {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    // The URL constructor is available in all browsers that support SW.
    const publicUrl = new URL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL, window.location.href);
    if (publicUrl.origin !== window.location.origin) {
      // Our service worker won't work if PUBLIC_URL is on a different origin
      // from what our page is served on. This might happen if a CDN is used to
      // serve assets; see https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2374
      return;
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`;

      if (isLocalhost) {
        // This is running on localhost. Let's check if a service worker still exists or not.
        checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl, config);

        // Add some additional logging to localhost, pointing developers to the
        // service worker/PWA documentation.
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(() => {
          console.log(
            'This web app is being served cache-first by a service ' +
              'worker. To learn more, visit '
          );
        });
      } else {
        // Is not localhost. Just register service worker
        registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
      }
    });
  }
}

function registerValidSW(swUrl, config) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(swUrl)
    .then(registration => {
      console.log('Service worker registered')

      registration.onupdatefound = () => {
        const installingWorker = registration.installing;
        if (installingWorker == null) {
          return;
        }
        installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
          if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
              // At this point, the updated precached content has been fetched,
              // but the previous service worker will still serve the older
              // content until all client tabs are closed.
              console.log(
                'New content is available and will be used when all ' +
                  'tabs for this page are closed. See '
              );

              // Execute callback
              if (config && config.onUpdate) {
                config.onUpdate(registration);
              }
            } else {
              // At this point, everything has been precached.
              // It's the perfect time to display a
              // "Content is cached for offline use." message.
              console.log('Content is cached for offline use.');

              // Execute callback
              if (config && config.onSuccess) {
                config.onSuccess(registration);
              }
            }
          }
        };
      };
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
    });

}


function checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl, config) {
  // Check if the service worker can be found. If it can't reload the page.
  fetch(swUrl, {
    headers: { 'Service-Worker': 'script' },
  })
    .then(response => {
      // Ensure service worker exists, and that we really are getting a JS file.
      const contentType = response.headers.get('content-type');
      if (
        response.status === 404 ||
        (contentType != null && contentType.indexOf('javascript') === -1)
      ) {
        // No service worker found. Probably a different app. Reload the page.
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
          registration.unregister().then(() => {
            window.location.reload();
          });
        });
      } else {
        // Service worker found. Proceed as normal.
        registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log(
        'No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.'
      );
    });
}

export function unregister() {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready
      .then(registration => {
        registration.unregister();
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error.message);
      });
  }
}
```

App.js file. The fetch event comes from there

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

const App = () => {
  const [name,setName] = useState("")
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({})
  const handleChange = e => setName(e.target.value);
  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log(`fetching information for ${name}`)
    fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${name}`)
        .then((res => res.json()))
        .then(data => {setUserInfo(data)
                        console.log(data)})
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
    <h1> Git user infor </h1>
    <div className={'form'}>
      <input type='text' value={name} onChange={handleChange} className={'text-box'}/>
      <input type='button' value={'Submit'} onClick={handleClick} className={'button'}/>
    </div>

    {Object.keys(userInfo).length > 0 && <div className={'table'}>
      <table>
        <tbody>
        {Object.entries(userInfo).map(([k,v], i) => {
          return <tr key={i}>
            <td>{k}</td>
            <td>{v}</td>
          </tr>
        })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>}
  </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I get `Yay! Workbox is loaded` but it does not seem to go into fetch.

*EDIT*
So, If I remove the `const IPFS = require('ipfs')
then everything works fine.
How can I incorporate that into my csw?

Answer (score 1):

Pascal,

Given so many moving parts it is hard to tell what exactly is going wrong. If bundling IPFS was a problem I would not expect to see `Yay! Workbox is loaded`, but then again it depends how does that resulting script looks like, specifically e.g. error  after `console.log` can cause service worker installation to fail and would explain why you see the logged message but nothing on fetch.

It is also worth considering that service workers have complex lifecycles:

- First load will not delegate fetch requests to service worker as it won't be activated by default until next load.
- Changed service worker script may not be picked up on the refresh and even if it is it still won't be activated (unless sw opts-into, which I don't see in your code).

This is the good article that goes over all these in a great detail and offers some tips in regards how to test and deal with complex lifetimes with devtools: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle

Now service worker part aside, it is also worth considering that running IPFS in the Service Worker itself, may not be ideal because:

Browsers deactivate SW as soon as it finished responding to a request (sometimes even sooner). Which works fairly well for typical server client architectures, but not so well with P2P architectures, because nodes needs to discover other peers and maintain healthy connections to be able to find and fetch content effectively.

That said, [recently it became possible to run JS-IPFS in SharedWorker](https://blog.ipfs.io/2020-09-14-js-ipfs-0-50/) and consume it's API in the other threads. Which creates an opportunity to consume shared IPFS node from the service worker as well. If that sounds aligned with your goals I'd suggest subscribing [to a relevant issues](https://github.com/ipfs-shipyard/ipfs-provider/issues/26).